# wifi problem on suspend - hardware disabled

Tags: wireless

[wireless-info-bad](https://pastebin.com/W8JJ6Fez)

[wireless-info-good](https://pastebin.com/5StV8Qnn)

Wifi works normally, however when the hp pavilion laptop is suspended-resumed the wifi stops working. I have the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04, 16.10 and 17

Comment: hibernate works fine. this workaround is acceptable for me!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a different driver available for your Wi-Fi device.

**Settings >Software and Updates >Additional Drivers**

Usually the first device listed will be your Graphics card (GPU). If at all a different driver is available for your Wi-Fi device, then it will show up there as a second device after the GPU, with radio buttons indicating which driver is currently in use and the other available drivers.

Choose the non selected driver and apply. It might download the necessary files (you will need a working internet). Apply and reboot.

Check if the problem is fixed.

Comment: In line 51 of your network stats, the bad state has "Hard blocked: yes", whereas in the good state, it is "Hard blocked: no". Are you using any dedicated hardware Wi-Fi switch while you suspend?

Comment: Settings>Software and Updates>Additional Drivers does not have different available driver. The only entry there is for "using processor microcode firmware for intel cpus"

Comment: Oh okay. Sorry to see that. You must have a hardware switch (something like Fn+F2 or similar combination. You can find the wireless symbol on your keyboard). Can you try pressing that once when you Wi-Fi if disabled when it wakes up from suspend? If it works, that can be a temporary fix to your problem, until you get more experienced advice. Resume from suspend>toggle Wi-Fi switch once.

Comment: I hit the power button to suspend, I do not see any Wi-fi switch. The F12 key has "airplane mode" symbol on it. After Ubuntu resumes from suspend state, there is an Airplane mode icon shown in the upper right corner. Pressing F12 (Fn + F12) does not toggle the Airplane mode.

Comment: Okay that airplane switch itself is the Wi-Fi/wireless switch. Please check out if you are doing the right way to toggle airplane mode. Getting that work could be of some relief to you